# How to update uiview after viewdidload?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, size, screen

I'm working on a project which I didn't start and now we discovered a bug on the first VC:
The first viewcontroller has a top bar menu and a bottom bar menu. the rest is a containerview that shows the viewcontrollers needed.
In `viewDidLoad`this method gets called:

```
    self.currentIndex = 0;

    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGRect contentViewFrame = screenBounds;

    // iPhone X
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {

        UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
        CGFloat topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top;
        CGFloat bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;

        contentViewFrame.origin.y = topPadding + 20.0; // 20 p for status bar
        contentViewFrame.size.height -= (rootView.bottomBarView.frame.size.height + (topPadding + 20.0) + bottomPadding); // topPadding + 20 statusbar

    } else {

        contentViewFrame.size.height -= rootView.bottomBarView.frame.size.height;

    }

    self.conversationVC = [[VOCConversationVC alloc] initWithFrame: contentViewFrame];
    self.diaryVC = [[VOCDiaryVC alloc] initWithFrame: contentViewFrame];
    self.managementVC = [[VOCManagementVC alloc] initWithFrame: contentViewFrame];

    self.viewControllerSelected = VOCViewControllerSelectedCommunication;
}
```

The thing is at `ViewDidLoad` point, `topPadding`and `bottomPadding` are still 0, therefore the frames are not set propertly. 
And if I change the `contentViewFrame` height after, it doesn't make any change in the view. I tried:

`viewDidLayoutSubviews`
`layoutIfNeeded`
`layoutSubviews`

and some other methods that didn't help. When I print the `contentViewFrame`height it's changed but no visible effects, so I'm missing what I'm doing wrong... Maybe one of the aboves methods I'm not using ton the proper view or in the proper moment? Or is it something else?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could try moving this code to either `viewWillAppear:animated` or `viewDidAppear:animated`.

IIRC, the variables you're trying to access will be set when one (or both) of these methods are called.